# Codeigniter session not visible in other pages

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, session, facebook-graph-api

Hi friends I am using codeingter default session library. I have created normal login and facebook login for my web application using this library.

Normal login was working properly with this library, when I tried to do the same with fb login , I am able to see the session variables only in the login page. When I go to different pages of the website session variables are not visible.

**FB login:-** print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); for login page is giving me the following array

> Array ( [session_id] => 18d8f5e5f8504289d848a137e6d8587b [ip_address]
>   => *** [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0 [last_activity] => 1425530911
>   [user_data] => [user_id] => 2262 [user_email] => **** [logged_in] => 1
>   [facebook_login] => 1 [admin] => [logout] =>
>   https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=*****&access_token=CAANoqwioFoQBACkl2krguKonH3nDamlowXcZCxhqhZAMa1ncOgazFdGXmkSB1QjnpZCweDa1MrXcWK1ZAgUUDHh7Xi7OEJSoJKvt8VXpWYeb3qfcz0mYXmzcLJqZCTFh4PheYD84zGq5u7Q1YQLINS1I7t6KU4EwlGxVMsZBKYjgFAt8tZA5CqSYQ168kvC329TqPZBF2ZAS8j6HfVFcHWsvO
>   )

where as for other pages the array is null

Please help me to resolve this issue.

This is the model which I am using for fb login

> 

```
 if($query->num_rows()>0)
>                 { 
>                         foreach($query->result() as $rows)
>                         {
> 
>                                 //add all data to session
>                                 $newdata = array(
>                                                 'user_id'  => $rows->id,
>                                                 'user_email'    => $rows->email,
>                                                 'logged_in'  => TRUE,
>                                                 'facebook_login' => TRUE,
>                                                 'admin'=>False,
>                                                 'logout' => $logout
>                                                 );
>                         }
> 
> 
>                         $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
> 
>                         $message = $this->session->all_userdata();
> 
>                         return true;
>                 }
```

Comment: Maybe you forget to load library in other pages.

Comment: No I have loaded the library by autoload, so its available in all the pages

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CI 3 all_userdata() is DEPRECATED, you can use userdata() with no parameters.

If the problem remain or your not using CI 3, you can use [Native Session](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session) library, because CI original session library has some problem.